# Framework for doing (Igoogle/Pageflakes/netvibes)-like application using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks, igoogle

Anyone has any suggestions of a framework to help me create an Igoogle/pageflakes/netvibes like application using ruby on rails.

I tried using [apotomo](http://apotomo.de/) for a few days, but couldn't make it work at all.

If not possible to make using ruby on rails, do u have any suggestions on what to use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

now, try it again! that's for you:

[How to make a dashboard in Rails with Apotomo](http://github.com/apotonick/dashboard_tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

For an iGoogle type portal you might check ExtJS. Here's a sample

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/portal/portal.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're more interested in back-end than front-end components. There doesn't seem to be publicly available Rails code for keeping track of a user's widgets at the moment, so you will have to make your own. Good thing you already know Rails!